# Use of the word "plead"

Tags: prepositions

"Plead" has lots of meanings, and one of them is to beg someone, so why is it necessary to use the preposition "with" with it? For example: Lend me your car please! I am pleading with you!

Comment: 'I beg you' needs a to-infinitival complement clause (unless used as a fragment). You can't say 'John begged Jack' without further context, so the verb behaves differently from say 'pay' in 'John paid Jack'. / 'Plead', as @WS2 says, has even more complex requirements (often sense-dependent). Though DOs are possible ('plead a case' is unarguably an example using one), the person pleaded with is not one of them. 'Argue', 'remonstrate', 'discuss' can't take the 'correspondent' as DO either. 'Debate' may take one ('He debated the president'), though this sounds very odd to many British ears.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Omission of the preposition following these types of intransitive verbs has become so common, that they begin to sound transitive. *Appeal* is another one - *the defence appealed (against) the decision of the lower court*.  Some will argue that it represents a metamorphosis of the language, others like me are less generous.

Comment: @WS2 Does OED give the date the transitive usage was first seen in print? Apparently, at least one transitive sense is now obsolete, so this transitive sense at least would seem pretty old./ There are a fair number of verbs that can be used with a choice of DO or prepositional phrase, with little change in meaning. Some choices have been around a long time. Brush [against] someone's leg. Fight [against/with] the Elbonians. Boo [at] the Elbonian team. Check [on] the condition of the brakes.  Distinguish [between] similar outcomes. Cross [over] the Forth Bridge. Mourn [for] his lost children....

Comment: I suspect  'these types' really means 'the ones I don't like'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plead is an intransitive verb, so it doesn't take a direct object.

Beg can be used transitively, so it can take a direct object.

Intransitive verbs require a preposition to join them to an object, hence why *plead* is followed by *with*.

*Beg* can also be used intransitively, so you can say both "I beg you" (transitive use) and "I beg of you" (intransitive use).

Pleading isn't exactly the same as begging, which is why they don't use the same preposition.

Comment: ***Plead*** is a varied and complicated verb. It is not always intransitive, especially in legal senses e.g. *1933   R. C. Hutchinson Unforgotten Prisoner xii. 383   One can commit perjury and plead absence of mind.* (OED - sense 6c). A judge, simply asking, *How do you plead, guilty or not guilty?* is a transitive sense.

Comment: Pleading guilty or not is not the begging sense.